# Как получить описание поля enum в asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, view, enum

Есть enum содержащий определенный набор значений (state)

```
public enum State : int {
CONNECTION_ERROR,
CONNECTION_COMPLETE,
WAIT_CONNECTION
}
```

В отчете есть значение поля State и оно выводится во view. Собственно выглядит например так: **Состояние : CONNECTION_COMPLETE.** Нужно что бы вместо названия поля enum'a выводился понятный текст (Ошибка соединение, Соединение завершено успешно, Ожидание соединения). Пробовал через атрибут [Display(name="...")] не помогло, выводится именно название строки в enum'e. Может кто знает как решить такую проблему?

Comment: Так, непрвильно вопрос назвал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать **Description** из компонентной модели:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Main {
    public enum State : byte
    {
        [Description("Ошибка соединения")]
        CONNECTION_ERROR,
        [Description("Соединение выполнено")]
        CONNECTION_COMPLETE,
        [Description("Ожидание соединения")]
        WAIT_CONNECTION
    }
}
```

Затем создаем расширяющий метод для перечислений, который будет возвращать нам описание:

```
namespace Main.Extensions
{
/// <summary>
/// Расширение Enum
/// </summary>
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Получить атрибут "Описание"
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Значение перечисления</param>
    /// <returns>Значение атрибута "Описание"</returns>
    public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
            (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
            false);

        if (attributes != null &&
            attributes.Length > 0)
            return attributes[0].Description;
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

И используем его:

```
State.CONNECTION_COMPLETE.GetDescription();
```